# Deeplinking in Xamarin.Android app not working

Tags: android, xamarin, deep-linking

in our app we are using deeplinks. They are working when the app is opened or runs in the background but not when the app is completely closed.

The app opens but neither the OnNewIntent nor the OnAppLinkRequestReceived is called.

I tried to move the intent filters from MainActivity to SplashActivity but no success.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to create the DeepLinking for the Xamarin.Android app.

First, please add the IntentFilter in the MainActivity. Here is the sample for you to refer to.

```
 [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "example.com",
    DataPathPrefix ="/",
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

In addition, you do not need to set the intent filter in the Manifest the c# will help you to build the configuration in the manifest.Then you can create an html link to test the Deeplinking.

> The app opens but neither the OnNewIntent nor the
> OnAppLinkRequestReceived is called.

For this issue, you can add the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the android manifest to create a new task and a new instance will be pushed to the task as the root one.

Comment: Hi, I have the launchMode already in the attribute of the MainActivity and SplashActivity:

LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask

When I put the intentFilters back to the MainActivity it calles the OnAppLinkRequestReceived, but I have now the problem, that there is not all stuff initialized and I got a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Where did the error occur in the code?

Comment: We use the CoreMethods from the FreshMVVM, but it is always null in that case.

Comment: This might be the error in the CoreMethods. The deeplinking will work if you set it successfully.